# Removing First and Last Character from string array

Tags: c, arrays, string

Hello im trying to find a way to remove the first and last character of an array of strings.

My data insight the array is something like this:

"Time1":

"3.0"

etc.

Im trying specifically to remove the double quotes and the char : 
What should i use?

```
char item[100]; 
   char  LastArray[1000];
   while (NewMixedArray[i] != NULL)
   {
    sscanf (NewMixedArray[i],"\"%99[^\"]", item);
    LastArray[i]=item;
    printf("%d %s\n",i,LastArray[i]);
    i++;
   }

   i=0;
   while (  LastArray[i] != NULL)
   {
    printf("DONE: %d %s\n",i,LastArray[i]);
    i++;
   }
```

On the second printf im getting only the last value.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcCRP.png

I found my problem i used the command

LastArray[i] = strdup(item); Because my LastArray was an array of pointers.

Comment: if its always first and last 2 characters you can use substring

Comment: `What method should i use?` "Method"? `memove` 1 byte to the front. Set the one character before zero terminating character to zero.

Comment: i tried user3121023 solution and after i extract it i want to save it but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char string[1000], result[1000];
    strcpy(string, "\"Time1\":");

    printf("\nInitial String : %s", string);
    int i;
    int c = 0;
    do {
        if (string[i] != '\"' & string[i] != ':') {
            result[c] = string[i];
            c++;
        }
        i++;
    } while (string[i] != '\0');

    printf("\nResult : %s\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

Result

```
$ ./ss

Initial String : "Time1":
Result : Time1
```